Calculate statistics from a list of dataframes in R by group or row
I'm conducting bootstrapping on my data and now need to calculate the mean and 95% CI. I've already resampled my data 1000 times and calculated a custom statistic, let's call it CS, which is a column in a dataframe. Now, I'm trying to either flatten/merge the list of the 1000 data frames or calculate the mean and confidence interval over the list of data frames in R, either row-wise or by a group (let's call that group column CNNgroup).
Build a sample list of dataframes
df1 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(0.01, 0.2, 0.1))
df2 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(-0.01, -0.2, -0.1))
df3 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(0.06, 0.8, 0.85))
mylist <- list(df1,df2,df3)

Desired output: (disclaimer, CI might not be calculated properly but you get the idea I hope)
CNNgroup CSmean    CIlow  CIhigh 
90      0.1033333   −0.133  0.339
91
92
93

I've tried using this post per the following code which results in all means being NA.
bind_rows(mylist) %>%
   group_by(CNNgroup) %>%
   summarise(value_mean = mean(CS, na.rm = TRUE))
 

I then tried flattening the list but lost the CNNgroup information...
do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, as.data.frame.table, na.rm = TRUE))

I'm a novice and it's taken me months to get my code this step so I'm fatigued and really appreciate the help.

What is mylist, is it df.list?

Yes, I just made that edit.

This can be done beautifully in base R (no dependencies).
do.call("rbind", mylist) |>
  aggregate(. ~ CNNgroup, FUN = \(x) c(mu = mean(x), low = quantile(x, .025), up = quantile(x, .975)))

giving
  CNNgroup      CS.mu CS.low.2.5% CS.up.97.5%
1       90  0.0200000  -0.0090000   0.0575000
2       91  0.2666667  -0.1800000   0.7700000
3       92  0.2833333  -0.0900000   0.8125000

Complete with na.rm=TRUE if needed. As long as you do not explain what you need besides the mean, we cannot demonstrate a solution.

Edit.
|> is the forward pipe operator introduced in R 4.1.0, see help(`|>`). If you are using older versions of R do
mydf = do.call("rbind", mylist)
aggregate(. ~ CNNgroup, mydf, FUN = \(x) 
          c(mu = mean(x), 
            low = quantile(x, .025), 
            up = quantile(x, .975)))

Also have a look on the documentation of aggregate and formula.
. ~ CNNgroup means "operate on all columns grouped by CNNgroup".

I can't get this to work. I'm copying it exactly. Are "|>" and ". ~" short-hand for something else? I'm a beginner and don't understand.

Please see my edit.

library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(0.01, 0.2, 0.1))
df2 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(-0.01, -0.2, -0.1))
df3 <- data.frame("CNNgroup" = c(90, 91, 92), "CS" = c(0.06, 0.8, 0.85))
mylist <- list(df1,df2,df3)

# or reframe() or summarise()
bind_rows(mylist) %>%
  reframe(value_mean = mean(CS, na.rm = TRUE), 
          lower_bound = quantile(CS, c(.025)),
          upper_bound = quantile(CS, .975), .by = CNNgroup)
#>   CNNgroup value_mean lower_bound upper_bound
#> 1       90  0.0200000      -0.009      0.0575
#> 2       91  0.2666667      -0.180      0.7700
#> 3       92  0.2833333      -0.090      0.8125


I think this is what I need but can't get it to work. reframe doesn't seem to be a tidyverse function...?

I was able to get this to work thanks to the help above. First, I bind all lists into one long data frame (they have the same columns).
Then, I grouped by CNNgroup, and did the stats.
library(dplyr)
 
BindSUB <- bind_rows(mylist)

BindSUB %>%
  group_by(CNNgroup) %>%
   summarise(value_mean = mean(CS, na.rm = TRUE), 
           lower_bound = quantile(CS, c(.025), na.rm = TRUE),
           upper_bound = quantile(CS, .975),na.rm = TRUE)

